# How can I insert this conditional statement so that a default image shows up when a blog post has no featured image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show a default image `isa.jpg` when a blog post has no featured image using the conditional statement below:

```
        <?php

            /* Previous Thumbnail */
            if ( $prevthumbnail ) {
            echo $prevthumbnail;
            } else {
             echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA" />';
            }

            /* Next Thumbnail */
            if ( $nextthumbnail ) {
             echo $nextthumbnail;
            } else {
             echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA" />';
            }

        ?>
```

This code below shows the featured images, but if no featured image is associated with the blog post, it just shows a blank area. This is why I want to show a default image in its place.

```
    <div id="next-prev-posts">
        <?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(); $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) ); ?>
        <?php $nextPost = get_next_post(); $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(100,100) ); ?>

        <div class="inner">
            <div class="nav-next">
                <?php if ($nextPost) { ?>
                <?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail", false); ?>
                <?php next_post_link('%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title', false) ?>
                <?php } else { echo "<p>You're at the beginning!</p>"; } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-previous">
                <?php if ($prevPost) { ?>
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">»</span>', false) ?>
                <?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail", false); ?>
                <?php } else { echo "<p>You're at the end!</p>"; } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to somehow combine the two blocks of code above so that the default image shows up if the blog post has no featured image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like a challenge. This is what I came up with. It might be a bit long, but I had to fix bugs as well in the code. Hope this helps

```
<div id="next-prev-posts">
        <?php
            $prevPost = get_previous_post(); 
            if(isset($prevPost->ID))
            $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) );
            $nextPost = get_next_post(); 
            if(isset($nextPost->ID))
            $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(100,100) ); 
            $default = '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA" />';
        ?>

        <div class="inner">
            <div class="nav-next">
            <?php
                if ($nextPost && '' != get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(100,100))) { 
                    next_post_link('%link', $nextthumbnail, false); 
                    next_post_link('%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title', false); 
                } elseif ($nextPost) {
                    next_post_link('%link', $default, false); 
                    next_post_link('%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title', false);
                } else {
                    print '<p>' . __( 'You are at the beginning!' ) . '</p>';
                }   
            ?>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-previous">
            <?php
                if ($prevPost && '' != get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100))) { 
                    previous_post_link('%link', $prevthumbnail, false); 
                    previous_post_link('%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title', false); 
                } elseif ($prevPost) {
                    previous_post_link('%link', $default, false); 
                    previous_post_link('%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title', false);
                } else {
                    print '<p>' . __( 'You are at the end!' ) . '</p>';
                }   
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be there's a more elegant way to write this, but try this one:

```
<?php
/* Check Thumbnail */
if ( !$prevthumbnail && !$nextthumbnail) {
    echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA";
    echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA";
}
elseif {
    /* Previous Thumbnail */
    if ( $prevthumbnail ) {
        echo $prevthumbnail;
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA" />';
    }

    /* Next Thumbnail */
    if ( $nextthumbnail ) {
        echo $nextthumbnail;
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/isa.jpg" alt="ISA" />';
    }
}
?>
```

Let me know.
Basically i put the check for $prevthumbnail and $nextthumbnail. Only after checking that at least one of them exist, it goes on the second conditional level, checking which one exist.